# CAML Query not returning rows

Tags: c#, sharepoint, caml

I'm sure this is obvious to someone else, but I cannot work out why this CAML query is not returning rows.

The list has 5 items, the ItemCount on the SP.Client.List confirms this, however when we try to query the list via CAML, we get 0 rows back in the ListItemCollection

```
ClientContext context = GetContext();
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List testList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Customers");
            context.Load(testList);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine(testList.ItemCount.ToString());


            CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
            ListItemCollection items = testList.GetItems(query);
            context.Load(items);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine(items.Count.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Camlex.Client.dll NuGet for creating CAML queries

`var caml = "<View>" + CamlexNET.Camlex.Query().Where(ee => ee["CustomerRef"] == 1121).ToString() + "</View>";`

Comment: That doesn't help as to what is wrong with the CAML query though ?

Comment: Check CustomerRef column type if it is Text then your CAML will return 0 items, becouse you have <Value Type='Number'> (if you will use u2u caml generator or camlex to create caml and view it you can see correct caml for your list and columns).

Comment: The value type in SharePoint is Number.  I am using a CAML generator, and that returns a row, the above identical query in C# doesn't

Answer (score 0):

The code below is working fine in my test environment.

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sp2013/sites/team");
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List spList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Customers");
clientContext.Load(spList);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

if (spList != null && spList.ItemCount > 0)
{
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View>
                            <Query> 
                                <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='CustomerRef' />
                                    <Value Type='Number'>1121</Value></Eq>
                                </Where> 
                            </Query> 
                            <ViewFields><FieldRef Name='CustomerRef' /></ViewFields> 
                        </View>";
    ListItemCollection listItems = spList.GetItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.Load(listItems);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(listItems.Count);
}
```

I suggest you check the "CustomerRef" field again.

[image]

Comment: yes, its 100% a number field

Intestingly if I do the following I don't get any rows back either, but splist.itemCount confirms there are row there:

Comment: Check if the current user have the permission to access the list items.

Comment: OK making this even more simple, and rulling CAML syntax issues.  You would expect the console out on both of the latest code up there to return the same value yes ?  Well the first one returns 5, the second 0.